# jquery clone date picker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Working on clone using datepicker. I have searched in stackoverflow for my issue i am not getting the correct stuff.  When the user clicks the date from the original date it was working as expected But once the user click the addmore button in the cloned div the datepicker was not working. I tried giving `.destroy` the result was not coming as expected.It might be the duplicate question but as I said the solution not working in my case.

Here is the jquery code.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
$(".cloned-row1").find(".deg_date").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+0",
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: new Date(),
    showButtonPanel: false,
    beforeShow: function () {
        setTimeout(function (){
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);

        }, 0);
    }
});
$(".deg_date").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
var count=0;
    $(document).on("click", ".edu_add_button", function () { 
        alert("checj");
        var $clone = $('.cloned-row1:eq(0)').clone(true,true);
        //alert("Clone number" + clone);
        $clone.find('[id]').each(function(){this.id+='someotherpart'});
        $clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_less1' id='buttonless'/>")
        $clone.attr('id', "added"+(++count));
        $clone.find(".school_Name").attr('disabled', true).val('');
        $clone.find(".degree_Description").attr('disabled', true).val('');
        $clone.find("input.deg_date").datepicker();
        $(this).parents('.educat_info').after($clone);
    });
    $(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function (){
        var len = $('.cloned-row1').length;
        if(len>1){
            $(this).closest(".btn_less1").parent().parent().parent().remove();
        }
    });
```

Here is the fiddle[link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/0389gq3k/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/0389gq3k/1/

Comment: @Sushil thanks for the help but in the clone i was not able to select month and year default date

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/0389gq3k/2/

Comment: did that work for you @Mahadevan?

Comment: thanks @Sushil works fine

Comment: great. let me post this as an answer then

Comment: can you please accept my answer and upvote it if it helped you @Mahadevan?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jquery `datepicker` creates UUID-based ID attributes for the input fields it binds when you initialize it. You cloning those elements results in more elements with either the same ID (which jQuery does not like) or a different ID if your clone routine manages that (*which means datepicker does not know about the clones*).

try updating your js code like this

```
$clone.find("input.deg_date")
    .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
    .removeData('datepicker')
    .unbind()
    .datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: "-100:+0",
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: new Date(),
        showButtonPanel: false,
        beforeShow: function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);

            }, 0);
        }
    });
```

here's the updated [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0389gq3k/2/). hope this helps.

Comment: i have one more query in the same row i have one date picker your code was not working for that can you please help me on that

Comment: you have to also remove id .removeAttr('id') http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/bepzbqpo/17/

Answer (score 0):

You can re-initiate datepicker,

Put datepicker line at last on click event

```
$(document).on("click", ".edu_add_button", function () { 
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  $(".deg_date").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
});
```

It will work!!!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to reinitialize a datepicker element by using datepicker function with a format as a param. Here's my case.

You don't have to destroy it or something like that.

I config to display the **Today** button, **Clear** button, and highlight today.

I also config an icon next to the datepicker input and whenever users click on an icon then the datepicker UI component would show.

```
    form.find('.datepickerClass').datepicker({
        format: 'd-m-Y',
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: 'linked',
        clearBtn: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
    });

    // Handle date picker button click event
    form.find('.datepickerClass').each(function() {
        $(this).next('.input-group-addon').click(function() {
            $(this).prev('input').focus();
        });
    });
```

[Datepicker UI Component image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWKkC.png)

It works for me. Always!!!